# Probabilistic algorithm, can a best case instance depend on the randomized parameter?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, probabilistic-programming, randomized-algorithm

Given this probabilistic algorithm (pseudo code):

```
p = random(1,n) // 1/n chance for each value ranging from 1 to n
if array[0] = p
{
loop that executes in tetha(n)
}
return 0;
```

EDIT : possible values in the array are 1..n

I would think that there is a best case instance (array[0] = p) however, this includes a randomized parameter and I have a feeling that it's not right. Am I wrong or right, and why?

Comment: What do you mean by a *best case instance*? If `array[0]` must be in the set `1, 2, ..., n`, then there is no best case. Probability 1/n to execute the loop, the complexity of which doesn't depend on `p`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the best-case analysis, you should not consider the probabilistic factors and the only required thing is there is only one case that can be happened (with a positive probability). Hence, the best case analysis is `array[0] != p`. Then, the time complexity is `Theta(1)`.

It's the same as the worst case analysis. Suppose `p` is given (not important it's randomly chosen or not). The worst case time complexity is `O(n)`.

However, as explcitlt there is a random factor in the algorithm, a rational choice here is average time complexity, which is `(n-1)/n + 1/n * Theta(n) = Theta(1)`. Because, the condition of the `if` will be satisfied with the probability `1/n` and others is `(n-1)/n`.